# Separate values in select dropdown from a JSON array in React

Tags: json, typescript, dropdown, html-select, react-tsx

I've created a select dropdown from a JSON file. The key I'm reading is an array :

```
"type": [
  "Grass",
  "Poison"
]
```

When the array have just one value, it works fine but when it has two like here, I have this result

[image]
This where I created my dropdown :

```
<select className="searchbar dropdown" onChange={(e)=>{setSearchTerm(e.target.value); setSearchType(3)}}>
    <option className="dropdown-title" selected disabled color='lightgray'>Type</option>
            {Data.map(types => (
                <option key={types.id} value={types.type}>
                    {types.type}
                </option>
            ))}
```

How can I separate the values in the dropdown ?
And is it possible to delete the duplicates ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean separate the values? As for the second question - just make it a set - `{new Set(Data).map(types => ... }`

Comment: @Adam if you can see in the photo I have GrassPoison but I want Grass alone and Poison alone that's what I mean when I say separated values

Comment: Show the structure of your JSON file. It's not what you rposted.